# How to define a state with JSON data (using react and axios)

Tags: json, reactjs, axios, state, get-request

I am a little confused about how to go about this. So I have this JSON file called posts.json.

```
 [ 
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Kylie Jenner",
    "content": "Social Media Public Figure",
    "disclaimer": "*Disclaimer: This user may have comment filtering turned on",
    "slug": "hello-world",
    "img" : "https://ilarge.lisimg.com/image/16801290/1080full-kylie-jenner.jpg",
    "banner" : "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a5/2b/96/a52b963809c7e64e538b113cccf61dda.jpg",
    "handle": "kyliejenner",
    "handlelink" : "https://www.instagram.com/kyliejenner/"
}
]
```

I am currently trying to make a GET request to an API(url) that also includes specific data from my json file. In this case it will include the celebs handle. This is what I have setup here on Graphs.js.

```
 export default class Graph extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

}

state = {
  handle: '',
}


componentDidMount() {
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/celebs/' + handle)
.then(response => {
  this.setState({ celebs: response.data })
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
})
}
}
```

I am aware this isn't right as this is where I am stuck. "+ handle" is to come from the json file.  I want to make a request to the url where /handle will match the handle directly from json file as defined "handle": "@kyliejenner". But I keep getting an error saying 'handle' is not defined  no-undef. No matter how I do it, I can't seem to get it right and keep getting the same error.

So how do I go about defining handle with the data from the json file passed into it? More specifically the handle data.

I apologize in advance if this isn't clear. Please let me know if you need further clarrification.

Comment: If the API call URL you wish to pass is http://localhost:5000/celebs/@kyliejenner, you will not be able to. The at symbol (@) is a special character in a URL and cannot be used in the URL.

Comment: Are you failing to _send_ the value over axios, or are you failing to _read_ the value from the file?

Comment: Okay so what if I remove the @? It's actually not necessary for it to be there. it really can just be kyliejenner. I will actually update that in my initial question.

Comment: I am failing to send the value over to axios. Because handle is currently undefined, but I am not sure how to define handle with the data from the json file.

Comment: it's this.state.handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in the comment by Sean, your local state is a bit wrong. You should declare it like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {handle: ''};
}
```

And use it like this:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/celebs/' + this.state.handle)
```

Or, using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/celebs/${this.state.handle}`)
```

More info in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

Comment: How do I go about passing the handle data from the JSON file into handle state this way?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want here. You can use `setState` like you did to save the JSON data loaded from Axios to your local state.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the json in a different file assign the data to an object and you can import it like this.

```
import posts from 'posts.js';
```

Now you have access to the posts object in your component, so you can just access it using

```
const handle = posts[i].handle; //pass the index of array(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I was wondering about making an external service call that returns an initialized object instead of having it in the app directly. I think the app would loose intellisense on the object properties though.